# How to iterate over datatable without columns iterator?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have the following code:

```
<p:dataTable id="oc_pc" editable="true" editMode="cell" rendered="#{dersRelation.isOC_PC}" value="#{dersRelation.rel_oc_pc}" var="oc_pc_rel">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        #{dersRelation.relName}
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dersRelation.onCellEdit}" update="main_form:growl,@this" />
                    <p:column headerText="Program Çıktıları">
                        <h:outputText value="#{oc_pc_rel.pc}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:columns value="#{dersRelation.ocs}" var="oc" columnIndexVar="colIndex" >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{oc.description}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{oc_pc_rel.values[colIndex]}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:rating value="#{oc_pc_rel.values[colIndex]}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>        
                    </p:columns>        
                </p:dataTable>
```

As it seems between column tags "oc" iterator is active. But i have to iterate with main iterator in table for "oc_pc_rel.values[colIndex]". This code fills all rows with count of "oc_pc_rel.pc". All rows refer to same index in rel_oc_pc collection. How can i fix that.

Comment: _" This code fills all rows with count of "oc_pc_rel.pc""_ I don't see that happening... ypur problem is unclear to me. Maybe add a screenshot of what isappening and a mockup of what you want. And make a [mcve] please...

Comment: PC count is initial row count, datatable creates rows with that but if i change a value in a cell all rows gets affected. All rows are the same.

Comment: And what if you use the index of the dataTable instead of the var?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, i tried using indexes but it didn't worked.

Comment: Strange since it works for me... [mcve] please